# normality of subgroup of odd prime index

Tags: group-theory

It is known that any subgroup of a group having index 2 is normal. Note that here 2 is a prime.

Is such a result true for some other odd prime ?.
That is, "does there exist an odd prime $p$ such that whenever a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ has index $p$, then $H$ is normal in $G$ ?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If $p$ is the smallest prime dividing the order of $G$ and $[G : H] = p$, then $H \trianglelefteq G$. This is a corollary of what is commonly referred to as the [Strong Cayley Theorem](http://www.mathreference.com/grp-act,cayley.html). See the final corollary of [this document](https://math.la.asu.edu/~kawski/classes/mat444/handouts/strongCayley.pdf) for a proof.

Comment: @Nimitz Kalra: Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the things answered here, I just want to add this one.

**Proposition** Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ a subgroup of prime *index* $p$, with gcd$(|G|,p-1)=1$. Then $G' \subseteq H$.

Note that this implies that $H \unlhd G$, and that it is in fact sufficient to prove that $H$ is normal, since then $G/H \cong C_p$ is abelian.

**Proof**  Firstly, we may assume by induction on $|G|$, that $H$ is core-free, that is core$_G(H)=\bigcap_{g \in G}H^g=1$. This means that $G$ can be homomorphically embedded in $S_p$. Let $P \in Syl_p(G)$ and note that because $|S_p|=p \cdot (p-1) \cdots \cdot 1$, $|P|=p$. By the $N/C$-Theorem, $N_G(P)/C_G(P)$ embeds in Aut$(P) \cong C_{p-1}$. By the assumption gcd$(|G|,p-1)=1$, we get that $N_G(P)=C_G(P)$. Since $P$ is abelian we have $P \subseteq C_G(P)$, whence $P \subseteq Z(N_G(P))$. We now can apply Burnside's Normal $p$-complement Theorem, which implies that $P$ has a normal complement $N$, that is $G=PN$ and $P \cap N=1$. Note that $|G/N|=p$.

Look at the image of $H$ in $G/N$. Then $G=HN$, or $HN=N$. In the latter case $H \subseteq N$, and $|G:H|=|G:N|=p$, whence $H=N$ and we are done if we can refute the first case. If $G=HN$, then $|G:H \cap N|=|G:N|\cdot|N:H \cap N|=|G:N|\cdot |G:H|=p \cdot p=p^2$, contradicting the fact that $|G| \mid |S_p|$. The proof is now complete.

**Corollary 1** Let $G$ be a finite group and let $H$ be a subgroup with $|G:H|=p$, the *smallest* prime dividing the order of $G$. Then $G' \subseteq H$. In particular, $H$ is normal.

**Corollary 2** Let $G$ be a finite group and let $H$ be a subgroup with $|G:H|=p$ and gcd$(|H|,p-1)=1$. Then $H$ is normal.

Observe that this last result renders a well-known result for $p=2$! Finally for fun:

**Corollary 3** Let $G$ be a finite group of *odd* order and $H$ a subgroup with $|G:H|=65537$. Then $H$ is normal.

Comment: interesting ! Thanks .