# Is this group always abelian?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $|G|$ be odd and its prime factorization contain a prime of the form $r=2^n+1$, if $H$ is a normal subgroup of order $r$, is $G$ abelian?

My reasoning goes like this:

Since $H$ is normal, $G/Z(G)\cong \text{Inn}(G) \subseteq \text{Aut}(H)\cong Z_{2^n}$, therefore $|G/Z(G)|$ must be a power of two by Lagrange's theorem. Because $|G|$ is odd, $Z(G)=G$.

The exercise in the text went like this:

If $G$ has order $3825$ and $H$ is a normal subgroup of order $17$, prove $H\subseteq Z(G)$. 

However, this is a weaker result than the one above, which prompts me to believe I might have made a mistake in the generalization, my problem is I do not see where.

Answer (score 0):

the mistake in the proof is assuming $\text{Aut}(H)\cong \mathbb Z_{2^n}$, this must not necessarily be the case.

Comment: Indeed! It's true however that the cardinality of group of automorphisms of a finite cyclic group must be an even number. If helps the proof somehow.

Comment: I realize now I made a mistake, but whether $\text{Aut} (H)$ is cyclic or not is irrelevant, since all we need is that its order is a power of $2$, a condition that does hold.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have $G/Z(G) \subset \operatorname{Aut}(H)$ in general. We *do* have a natural homomorphism from $G$ to $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ which sends an element to conjugation by that element, but the kernel of that map is the centralizer of $G$ which may be larger than than $Z(G)$.

(Consider the case that $H$ is the trivial subgroup, for example)

Comment: But $G/Z(G)\cong \text{Inn}(G)$ (set $\phi (g)= gxg^{-1}$, now $\phi (gh)=\phi(h)\circ \phi(g))$, $\phi$ is also surjective, and by the first isomorphism theorem we have that they are isomorphic because $\text{ker} \phi = Z(G)$. Also, every inner automorphism of $G$ fixes $H$ since $H$ is normal, therefore it is an automorphism of $H$.

Comment: @GuachoPerez There's no embedding of $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ into $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$, in general.

Comment: @GuachoPerez you have defined a map from $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$ to $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$, but there is no reason for it to be injective, because it may very well be the case that an element acts nontrivially on $G$ by conjugation, but it acts trivially on $H$ by conjugation.

Comment: @MatheiBoulomenos so the mistake in the "proof" is saying that $\text{Inn} (G) \subseteq \text{Aut}(H)$ or that $\text{Inn} (G) \cong K \subseteq \text{Aut}(H)$?

Answer (score 0):

**Proposition 1** Let $G$ be a group of odd order and $H$ a normal subgroup with $|H|=p$, where $p$ is a [Fermat prime](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatPrime.html). Then $H \subseteq Z(G)$.

**Proof** Since $G$ acts by conjugation on $H$ we have an injective homomorphism $G/C_G(H) \hookrightarrow Aut(H)$. Since $H$ is cyclic, $|Aut(H)|=$ power of $2$. But $|G|$ is odd, so $G=C_G(H)$, which is equivalent to $H$ being central.

**Proposition 1 (dual)** Let $G$ be a group of odd order and $H$ a subgroup with $|G:H|=p$, where $p$ is a [Fermat prime](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatPrime.html). Then $G' \subseteq H$. In particular $H$ is normal.

**Proof** This is more subtle and uses Burnside's Normal $p$-Complement Theorem, for a proof, see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094950/normality-of-subgroup-of-odd-prime-index).